# NUnit Theory replaces Test?

Tags: nunit

I have seen many theories about Theory but the truth is that none of them is good enough to explain why not always use Theory. I do not see a reason (apart of ... well ... that the words Theory and Test are not the same words) why not always use a Theory.

The funny thing is that in all examples out there you could easily setup your test to be either a Test or a Theory and I am sure I am missing something here but I do not see the need to put myself in a philosophical uncertainty about what type of attribute I should use.

Let's suppose that the difference is only for the sake of self documented code. Then, why you use Datapoint and DatapointSource for Theory and something else for Test?

The truth is that I feel that nobody has come with a simple and clean answer that lights where the difference really is. At least one example where Theory makes absolute no sense and Test nicely fit, or the other way...

As a programmer I am.....If the answer is not simple there is something wrong there so.. help me to see what i am missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are referring to NUnit, I'll answer WRT what NUnit means by a theory. Note that this is entirely different from how xUnit.Net uses the term.

I got the idea of theories from JUnit and particularly from the work of David Saff. Here's one paper on the subject: http://groups.csail.mit.edu/pag/pubs/test-theory-demo-oopsla2007.pdf Google "saff theories" and you'll find more.

Basically, when creating a test you sometimes have a theory about how the tested code should work. (In this answer, lower case theory is the English word while Theory is the NUnit thing) This is especially common in mathematical reasoning. For example, consider a program that calculates square roots. I could theorize that the square root of any non-negative number is a value such that it gives the original number when multiplied by itself. That's a completely self-contained statement about the computation.

Using NUnit, I could write a test like this...

```
public void SqrtTest(double value)
{
    Assume.That(value >=0 );
    double answer = SquareRootOf(value);
    Assert.That(answer*answer, Is.EqualTo(value));
}
```

This test works no matter what number we give it. If the number is negative, the result is inconclusive and doesn't affect the overall outcome. If it is positive, an actual assertion is performed and the test either succeeds or fails.

In the ideal world, the provided values can come from anywhere. In JUnit, they come from Datapoints and I copied that. I also permitted them to be programmer-specified mainly as an interim solution. Ultimately, the idea was that the test framework would support a range of ways to generate data for a Theory, without the intervention of the programmer or tester.

Unfortunately, we are still waiting for that last bit. :-)

Bottom line, I think you should use Theory when you have a theory. Use a test when you just have examples without any logic binding them together. IME that's what happens in most business applications.

One of these days I hope to write a pretty long chapter about Theories.

Comment: Your answer is very convincing. Still I have a few questions (only because I want to learn more) but I think I got the general idea. Well, my question: If you can restrict the input to a theory through data points, aren't you converting the theory into a test after all?

Comment: Yes, in theory. :-)

Comment: In a way, selecting the datapoints makes the approach less "pure" but in practice, because the Theory uses the datapoints it discovers for each argument combinatorially, you get issues you had not forseen. Of course, you can also use random parameters to create even more datapoints.